# Convert Radar Polar coordinates to geographic coordinates

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, cartesian-closed-categories

I have found a lot of people asking questions about converting Polar coordinates to Geographic coordinates.

```
polar = latitude + 90°
azimuthal = longitude

radius = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
latitude = arcsin(z/radius)
longitude = atan2(y, x)

x = radius * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude)
y = radius * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude)
z = radius * sin(latitude)
```

I have Radar sensor data in Polar Coordinate.

- Distance, RadialVelocity, AzimuthAngle, ElevationAngle

Basically, I need Radar data in geographic coordinates.
**longitude distance and latitude distance,
longitude Velocity and latitude velocity**

If I replace radius by distance

- is longitude distance equal to longitude in the equation?
- is latitude distance equal to latitude in the equation?

Similarly, is applied for velocity.

(additional question, if anyone know are there built-in functions in C++
for this conversion?)

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I don't understand. You should edit your question and add an example of what you have, the equations you use and the result you look for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question. I hope you understand now.
I have something like (Distance, AzimuthAngle, ElevationAngle) and I need (longitude distance, latitude distance). My question: are the above-given equations correct?

Comment: Better thanks. Also, it would be good to know where did you take that vocabulary from. I mean, by "geographical coords" I understand the same as "polar coords": Radius, Longitude (an angle) and Latitude (an angle too). Cartesian coords are (x,y,z). "Radar coords" seems the same as polar ones, and "velocities" seem in the same direction as their tags (radial, etc). Also, be aware that any coordinates system needs and origin (center of Earth) and an orientation (Ecuator, Greenwitch meridian, etc), There's no defined cartesian orientation.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I guess I got the answer, what I am looking for in m (unit) Longitude and Latitude here are the angles. I need to focus on what exactly longitude distance and latitude distance are here.